# Compose components in native view

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, epoxy

I have an epoxy recycler view, and I want to create some of this views by using jetpack compose.

My question is that, Is it good to do that and I have no Idea about this page performance, because this screen is very important for my application.

Thanks